# Artifact config of AWS codebuild project not executed in AWS Code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cicd, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

As part of CI/CD, I have an aws codebuild project that builds a jar file and I am storing the jar file in an AWS s3 bucket using Artifact config as shown in the image and it works fine.
But when i use the above project as part of build stage, I don't see the artifact config of the build project and am unable to store the jar file to s3.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2omZ.png).

The build project itself will work fine but as part of a pipeline, the artifact store fails.
I have just one action group in each stage of the pipeline.

Thank you.